# How do I get Postgresql as an option in Visual Studio 2015 Data Connections

Tags: visual-studio, postgresql, sqldatasource

I have an asp.net project where I want to interact with my Postgres database through my Code Behind and.

I have been able to use Npgsql (added through Nuget) to query the DB in the C# code behind but it dosent seem to be meeting my needs, since I want to integrate it with an asp datasource.

When I try to setup a Data Connection in the Server explorer window I am unable to sort out the process.

How do I get this as an option?  Is it available?

Andy

Ive also been here  https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.PostgreSQL/7.4.506/.  and installed it but am still not getting the option..

Comment: "ASP Datasource" : are you sure you are looking to use something that died 14 years ago, when it was replaced by .NET and C#? Why do you think that `Npgsql` doesnt' meet your needs? Whether PostgreSQL appears in Server Explorer or not, has nothing to do with your code anyway. *Your* code uses ADO.NET with a provider and connection string specified in your `web.config`

Comment: `Server Explorer` is just that - a view to your servers that has no relation to your code.

Comment: Thanks.. I am still learning and have lots to go.  The ref is there as stated in the 'web.config'  I will try to understand more of the web.config and how to interact with it.

Comment: You should search for a tutorial on ADO.NET, not web.config. ADO.NET is the data access library

Comment: Thanks, I will..  Found a good looking tutorial and will work it.  Thanks again.  I appreciate the direction.

Comment: Thanks again Panagiotis... the tutorial answered my questions.  For anyone out there who is curious.  https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/adodotnet-by-example/table-of-contents